# Why is ui-router template not loading anymore?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the ui-router in my angular 1.4 app. I currently have the ng-app like this:

```
<div class="container main-content" ui-view ng-app="myApp">

</div>
```

The templates are loading fine directly. I know need to move the ng-app directive to the html tag:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
...

</html>
```

I am using a modulebased approach per page:

```
$stateProvider.state('myview', {
                url: '/myview/:id',
                templateUrl:'app/modules/myview.html',
                controller: 'MyViewController'
```

So each page has a state definition seperately.

After moving the ng-app to the html tag when I click on a different route the url changes in the browser but wont load the template? Is this related to the ui-router config or something else?

Comment: what are you loading in your variables `appConfig.viewBasePath` ?? usually to make a dinamyc template you should use `templateProvider` to change it according what do you need.

Comment: I removed it resulting in the same issue

Comment: isn't nothing in your console?? check your `$state` using the console on the `.run()` maybe you can see there in which state are you, when this happens

Comment: It actually does not change the state.current.name , just the url in the browser for some reason

Comment: can you make a fiddle? trying to replicate the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that instead of using ui-sref as a link href was used.